# Problema al mostrar datos

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo este script al momento de ejecutar me muestra error

**Tablas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controller**

```
$menu=DB::table('menu')
                    ->select('menu','url','id_menu')->get();

    $submenu=DB::table('sub_menu')->join('menu','sub_menu.id_menu','=','menu.id_menu')
                    ->select('sub_menu.nombre','sub_menu.url')->get();

    return view('home', compact('menu','submenu', 'broker'));
```

**Vista**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($menu as $item)
        <li>
            <a href="{{ $item['url'] }}">{{ $item['menu'] }}</a>
            @if (count($item['submenu'])) 
                <ul>
                @foreach ($item['submenu'] as $subitem)
                    <li><a href="{{ $subitem['url'] }}">{{ $subitem['nombre'] }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
```

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia tus imágenes por código en texto. Así como está es posible que no reciba la atención que esperas.

Comment: Ya lo hago. gracias

Comment: Qué te muestra si en el controlador ejecutas `dd($menu);`? Agrega ese código justo antes de `return view('home', compact('menu','submenu', 'broker'));`

Comment: Este es el error que tengoCannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistemas_Laravel\SistemaLogin\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: Me muestra todos los item de la tabla menu

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas usando un `StdClass` como si fuera un `array`, aquí puedes ver (documentación de Laravel) como ellos mismos dicen que lo que te va a devolver es una `StdClass`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

¿Como obtener un `array`? Es fácil, después de `->get()` debes poner un `->toArray()` de esa manera obtienes los resultados y lo pasas a un `array`.